# How to access external HDD from tails OS?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, tails

I am booting to tails OS using a flash drive of sandisk 32 GB. When it is powered on, I connected one more external HDD of 500 GB to the machine. But it is not showing. How to access and also how to partition the HDD from this tails OS on another usb flash drive?

Comment: What disk partitioning tools do you have installed?  You should edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: No, I didn't install any tools yet. The HDD is already partitioned.

Comment: Update your question to include that fact

Answer (score 0):

> I connected one more external HDD of 500 GB to the machine. But it is not showing.

Such drives are not automatically mounted in Tails. You can see and mount your devices with the software called Disk manager, shipped in Tails